# Error while using React-table.js in Vue.js

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, react-table

am trying to integrate https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme in vue.js app using https://github.com/akxcv/vuera.

My main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VuePlugin } from 'vuera'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VuePlugin)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
})
```

My HelloWorld.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>

    <ReactTable :data="data" :columns="columns" />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  components: { ReactTable },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      columns: [{ Header: 'Name', accessor: 'name' }],
      data: [ {name: 'tom'}]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Upon running this code I get two errors in console:

```js
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: children is not a function"

found in

---> <ReactWrapper>
       <ReactTable>
         <HelloWorld> at src/components/HelloWorld.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

and:

```js
vue.esm.js?efeb:1717 TypeError: children is not a function
    at ReactTable.render (index.js?5f89:822)
    at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:793)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:73)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:792)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:819)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:359)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:255)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?c56c:43)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:368)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:255)
```

Is it something wrong I'm coding or vuera plugin just doesn't handle ReactTable component integration correctly?

Many thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Possible to get a minimal git repo? Else setting up the environment eats up some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I recreated the project and it worked fine for me, below are set of dependencies I used. I think your case it might be just version mismatch issue

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-table": "^6.8.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuera": "^0.2.1"
  }
```

Please make sure you try with above version. The output is

[image: Working]

The project is available on below link if you want to just clone and test

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/react-vue-integration

Comment: Sorry for delay approval of answer. Managed to clone your repo and get it working! Thanks a lot for your effort, much appreaciated!